# What is the appropriate method for appending/removing <template> to/from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experimenting with adding HTML to the DOM for a small game I'm writing. My design calls for a main-menu system to be brought up first, where-in I'd like to pop in and remove sets of elements.

My question is, what is the most efficient method to do this? After some research, I have implemented  elements in the main body with IDs representing the menu section they contain. They look something like this:

```
<template id="main">

    <div class="wrapper_inner">

        <main id="main_screen">

            <h1>Main menu</h1>

            <nav class="vertical">

                <button type="button">Characters</button>

                <button type="button">Planets</button>

                <button type="button">Export...</button>

                <button type="button">Settings</button>

            </nav>

        </main>

    </div>

</template>
```

---

Then, I call these functions to change menus:

```
function clearMenu()
{
    var content = document.querySelector('.wrapper_inner');
    if(content) document.body.removeChild(content);
}
function menuSystem(mode)
{
    clearMenu();
    document.body.appendChild(document.querySelector('template#'+mode).content.cloneNode(true));
}
```

---

> **UPDATE: The problem is within the `cloneNode()` function.** It seemingly
>   creates an inaccessible document-fragment in passing to the body. If
>   someone can find a solution for this, I'll update best answer.

---

However... This is causing quite a problem in extended testing. I will only be changing menus a few times per session, I'm sure, but I'd like to maintain maximum efficiency. The problem shows up here:

```
function test()
{
    console.log("start test...");
    var start = new Date();
    for(var i=0; i<10000; i++)
    {
        menuSystem("main");
    }
    clearMenu();
    console.log("test completed in " + Math.round(((new Date())-start)/1000) + " secs");
}
```

---

This outputs around 5-7 seconds the first time, *16 seconds* the second time. In Chrome Dev Tools, though I am struggling to understand the output, I can see for each unique "mode" I switch to it adds a documentfragment or two to memory, which is not removed...Also, in the Heap snapshot after running test(), HTMLBodyELement has two HTMLBodyElement objects in it, one with a normal number of elements, and another with thousands of them.

To reiterate: What is the best method to do what I require here? Can my current method be fixed? What's the deal, anyway?

Comment: Use document fragments, don't append to the DOM directly on each iteration: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/ - also you might want to cache that querySelector call too

Comment: As far as I can tell, <templates> are documentfragments, are they not?

Comment: No, they are still DOM elements just rendered differently. Also, you are creating a new DOM element which is *not a template* inside `modalSystem` and appending that to the DOM, so you're still not using fragments there.

Comment: @RGraham: From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element): *"Each `template` element has an associated `DocumentFragment` object that is its **template contents**."* *(their emphasis)* This is what the OP is using above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As I read it, the `<template>` is a special DOM node, the `contents` property is set to a document fragment? But they're taking a clone of that fragment and adding it to the DOM - shouldn't they be appending it to a newly created document fragment instead?

Comment: @RGraham I tried that, and got a 2x longer run time on `test()`. The problem with my code here, I believe, is that somewhere DOM elements are not being removed in the clearMenu() function. I just don't know why that is, as they are usually only kept around after `.removeChild()` if they are referenced in the script, right?

Comment: @RGraham: I don't see any reason for passing the clone through a second document fragment.

Comment: @DanieClawson: Yeah, I don't see anything in your quoted code that would keep the cloned elements hanging around. But again, you're introducing memory churn by cloning and destroying the elements, so if you're seeing issues with that, showing/hiding is probably a better bet.

Comment: Updated the code in my question based on the comments here. Note that it is still broken. After digging some more I can see that it is the now-empty document-fragment clones that are not being garbage collected. I still can't tell why that is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder @RGraham I also tried `function menuSystem(mode)
{
 clearMenu();
 var newContent = document.body.appendChild(document.querySelector('template#'+mode).content.cloneNode(true));
 delete newContent;
}` but it leaves empty `<template>` elements for each iteration of `test()`

Comment: @DanieClawson: `delete` has nothing to do with memory management in JavaScript. More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869712/new-without-delete-on-same-variable-in-javascript/4869723#4869723

Comment: Thanks for the advice and discussion guys. Further investigation shows it's actually `.cloneNode` creating an (as far as I can tell) inaccessible `document-fragment` which does not get cleaned up. Using your solution, @T.J.Crowder Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, you're better off *showing* and *hiding* elements rather than *adding* and *removing* them. So just put the elements in your markup, then to hide an element:

```
document.querySelector("some selector").style.display = "none";
```

and to show it:

```
document.querySelector("some selector").style.display = "block";
```

...or `"inline"` or `"inline-block"` as appropriate.

Or use a class to hide it, and remove the class to show it again:

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

To hide:

```
document.querySelector("some selector").classList.add("hidden");
```

To show:

```
document.querySelector("some selector").classList.remove("hidden");
```

IE8 and IE9 (and a couple of niche browser) [don't have `classList`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist), but if you look around you can find a shim/polyfill for it.

---

<s>Side note 1: Your code for adding an element creates an invalid structure, because you don't remove the `id` from the cloned element, but then you append it. That means you end up with two elements in the document with the same `id`, which is invalid.</s> *(The OP is using `<template>` elements and appending their **content**, not them. Look more closely, Teej!)*

Side note 2: Your code for removing an menu item could be sped up by remembering the element you found rather than calling `document.querySelector` twice. E.g.:

```
function clearMenu()
{
    var wrapperInner = document.querySelector('.wrapper_inner');
    if(wrapperInner) {
        document.body.removeChild(wrapperInner);
    }
}
```

A [synthetic test](http://jsperf.com/queryselector-reuse) suggests that doubles the speed of things (which may seem obvious, but wouldn't be the case with the older methods like `getElementsByTagName`). Of course, this only matters if you see an actual performance problem, but as that's why you're posting...

Comment: Absolutely. This of course means that any event handlers would need to take into consideration elements can be hidden.

Comment: @RGraham: Indeed yes.

Comment: So it would not be considered bad form if I had several GUI layers in my HTML that have to be preloaded and then hidden before interaction with the game? For example, currently I have three potential layers (With sublayers?), like: Main-menu layer->login,start screen,characters screen,settings screen,pause screen || game gui layer with character health etc || in-game-menu layer->inventory,container inventory,store,etc

Comment: @DanieClawson: *"...have to be preloaded and then hidden..."* You can preload them in a hidden state (`style="display: none"` on the tag, or using a class that hides them).

Comment: About side note 1: I wasn't aware that was an issue when using <templates>

About preloading in hidden state: I'm aware, I just wonder if that isn't a lot of data on the front end that doesn't necessarily need to be dealt with at run time.

Comment: @DanieClawson: Doh! Of course, you're using templates. (In your case, literally `template` elements, but the same sort of thing would still have been fine just using `childNodes`, I should have been paying more attention, you're quite clearly using `.contents`.)