# Is calling new class on same variable cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function like this

`function runThis(){
  var class = new aClass();
  // using the class variable
 }`

if i run this function several times, can this cause a memory leak or that new class automatically destroyed?

Comment: No leaks, the new class is destroyed after the function has been executed, provided you're not returning any reference to the object outside of the function.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869712/new-without-delete-on-same-variable-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new class gets destroyed when you go out of the scope (out of `runThis` in this case) or when you re-assign the variable. The memory gets cleaned only when a new cycle of the garbage collector is ran, like in Java.
To learn more about garbage collection you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

This is not much different than Java or other high-level programming languages, but it still presents some caveats. 
Note that `var` preserves the variable hoisting. Maybe you'd prefer using `const` or `let`.